# Access Elements of Vector - C++

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
class Friend
{
public:
    Friend();
    ~Friend(){}
    void setName(string friendName){ name = friendName; }
    void setAge(int friendAge) { age = friendAge; }
    void setHeight(int friendHeight) { height = friendHeight; }
    void printFriendInfo();

private:
    string name;
    int age;
    float height;
};
//implementations
Friend::Friend()
{
    age = 0;
    height = 0.0;
}
//printing
void Friend::printFriendInfo()
{
    cout << "Name       : " << name << endl;
    cout << "Age        : " << age << endl;
    cout << "Height     : " << height << endl << endl;
}
```

And At this moment I can introduce the values in a vector, like this:

```
std::vector<Friend> regist(4, Friend());

regist[1].setAge(15);
regist[1].setHeight(90);
regist[1].setName("eieiei");
regist[2].setAge(40);
regist[2].setHeight(85);
regist[2].setName("random");
```

In debug, this solution works fine. But now I am trying to print the vector. So far without success.

```
for (int i = 0; i < regist.size(); i++) {
        cout << regist[i]; //<-- error here
        cout << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: And "without success" means...?

Comment: The reason why you can't is that the operator << can't be applied on the Friend type. It's only working with several native C++ types. You can overload the operator on your Friend class, or use your custom print function.

Comment: You have to explicitly implement [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).  You can implement it as a `friend` to give access to private members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might redesign a bit (in essence):

```
#include <iostream>

class Friend
{
public:
    Friend();
    // A more general name, const, and taking a stream.
    void write(std::ostream&) const;

private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    float height;
};

Friend::Friend()
{
    age = 0;
    height = 0.0;
}

void Friend::write(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    stream << "Name       : " << name << std::endl;
    stream << "Age        : " << age << std::endl;
    stream << "Height     : " << height << std::endl << std::endl;
}

// Forward to the member function
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const Friend& object) {
    object.write(stream);
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    Friend f;
    std::cout << f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `printFriendInfo()` member function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < regist.size(); i++) {
        regist[i].printFriendInfo();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
    cout << regist[i];
```

to work, add a few accessor functions in `Friend`

```
string getName() const { return name; }
int getAge() const { return age; }
float getHeight() const { return height; }
```

and implement an overloaded `operator<<` function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Friend const& f)
{
    out << "Name       : " << f.getName() << std::endl;
    out << "Age        : " << f.getAge() << std::endl;
    out << "Height     : " << f.getHeight() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```